# How much more disk space does wal_level logical compared to replica consume?

Tags: postgresql, backup, database-replication, wal

I setting the **wal_level** in my postgresDB from default replica to **logical**.
That I'm able to use debezium.

I wondered how much more disk space that will take up over time ?

A real life example would be great.

Something like:

1 Moth with roughtly the same amount of data changes.

- with replica the disk space consumed 100 more mb
- with logical the disk space consumed 200 more mb

I just assume wal_level logical will consume more space, is this even correct ?

Comment: That depends on your workload. Test it, it is simple.

Comment: I tried the following "test". I started 2 docker containers one with **wal_level logical** one with **wal_level reolica**. I inserted the northwind data example in both of them [northwind data from github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pthom/northwind_psql/master/northwind.sql)
exec into docker container `cd /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal ` and `ls -l --block-size=M` both first files had the same size of 16M and the second file 1M. No diffence, can you suggest another test ? Or does that mean it takes up the same space ?

Comment: It takes up the same size, which is not surprising if you restore a dump. Try a couple of updates and deletes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes you are correct. I tried some updates and deletes and the size does not change at all. When I use `show log_destination ;` I get 
`log_destination 
-----------------
 stderr
(1 row)`
Which just means its in cache of the docker itself. Also cannot find stderr.
Any suggetions where I actually can see the logs inside of the container or why the size within `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal` is not changing ?